# How to find out which files are being linked with "-lc"?

Tags: c, linux, clang, cross-compiling, libc

After spending almost an hour on filtering output of

```
clang -v hello_world.c
```

I got the following linking command:

```
ld -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
hello_world.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Is there an easier way to find out that `-lc` will expand to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`?

I need to know which files are used so I can copy them to another system for cross compiling.

*edit*

Looks like I should use the cross-compile toolchain. From clang docs:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

> When you have extracted your cross-compiler from a zip file into a
>   directory, you have to use --sysroot=. The path is the root
>   directory where you have unpacked your file, and Clang will look for
>   the directories bin, lib, include in there.

Where can I get that zip file they refer to? I'm interested in `x86_64-linux-gnu` target.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on why you want to know; please explain your larger goals.  Also, I strongly suspect you have removed too much stuff from the linking command.

Comment: @zwol I need to know which files are used so I can copy them to another system for cross compiling. This command successfully cross-compiles hello world.

Comment: @Alex, the usual approach to cross compiling involves installing and using a cross-compiling toolchain, which will include an implementation of the appropriate cross C standard library.  You should not need to do *any* of what you describe doing.

Comment: @Alex This may be enough for hello world, but in order to compile arbitrary programs you definitely need at least `libgcc.a` and `libgcc_s.so` as well (yes, those libraries have "GCC" in their name, but clang-compiled code may still need them), and you _may_ also need `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` (I can't remember if those still do anything meaningful).

Comment: @Alex ... and I was also about to say what John Bollinger just said.

Comment: So there's no way to say what files "-lc" is going to link to?

Comment: clang's cross compilation docs don't explain how to do that. All they say is "When you have extracted your cross-compiler from a zip file into a directory..." Where can I get that zip file for linux?

Comment: Besides as the docs say `Another problem is that compilers come with standard libraries only (like compiler-rt, libcxx, libgcc, libm, etc), so you’ll have to find and make available to the build system, every other library required to build your software, that is specific to your target. It’s not enough to have your host’s libraries installed.` I'll need other libraries, not just libc, so I'll still need to do this manually.

Comment: @Alex, your cross-compiling toolchain should come with cross versions of *all* libraries  that the compiler implementation and its target C standard library inherently depend upon.  In fact, that's part of what your quotation is saying -- it's listing examples of libs that you can expect the cross compiler to provide.  What *you* need to provide is any *other* libs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger where can I find/download libc for Linux? I have clang installed with brew.

Comment: @Alex, *it will come with your whatever-to-Linux cross toolchain*.  Such a toolchain would otherwise be incomplete.  You do not need to download a libc implementation separately, you should not try to do so, and if you *do* do so then your effort is probably wasted, as it is unlikely that a separately-downloaded version would in fact be used.

Comment: But that's the thing. I have no idea where to look for it. Everyone says "it comes with the toolchain". But where is it?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html `When you have extracted your cross-compiler from a zip file into a directory` Where can I get that zip file? On the website I can only download the source.

Comment: You don't need to know.  There are *other* target tools and libraries that are not included with the toolchain that you may need to provide, but that's an altogether separate question.  If you're just curious then browse the unpacked toolchain directory or use the `find` command strategically, but this information is not required to successfully perform cross compilation.

Comment: But says right in the docs `When you have extracted your cross-compiler from a zip file into a directory, you have to use --sysroot=<path>.` I don't know what the path is and where the zip file is.

Comment: My question is very simple. Where do I get that zip file, the clang cross compiling docs refers to.

Comment: @Alex, "When you have extracted your cross-compiler from a zip file into a directory" is about how you install(ed) the cross compiler.  If you installed it that way then you should know where it is.  The ZIP (or other form of archive file) in question would be that for clang itself, presumably from http://releases.llvm.org/download.html.  If you *did not* install it that way, then those provisions of the docs probably do not apply to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list all the files linked to `libc.so.6`:

```
for i in `find . -type f -executable`
do
    j=$(ldd $i | grep libc.so.6 | wc -l)
    if [ $j -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

In case you want to find out what the path of `libc.so.6` is, stated in the original question something similar to:

```
ldd `which ld` | sed 's/^[[:space:]]libc.so.6[[:space:]]=>[[:space:]]\(.*\)[[:space:]](.*)/\1/p' | grep --color=never libc.so
```

will type the path, you can obviously replace the expression after ldd with any filename.

From the comments, there is a way with clang directly though it will generate a lot of noise which is significantly harder to exclude compared to the ldd way.

```
clang -Wl,--verbose hello_world.c
```

will tell the linker to be verbose and it will eventually tell you all the library paths tried for each library.

Comment: ... but only for shared libraries, not static ones.  And there are other issues with this, too, though it may indeed yield useful information.

Comment: But `ldd` what? :) I'm trying to find the filename out.

Comment: @Alex Edited the answer, I hope this is what you were looking for, if not please clarify further.

Comment: Thanks @xception your final command does what I want. So there's no easy way to ask the C compiler which file it actually uses when it encounters `-lc` or `-lm` etc. They have to be manually searched.

Comment: @Alex if we're talking about a very large number of files and performance is a concern I took inspiration for this script from gentoo's revdep-rebuild bash script, there is a python version which is significanlty faster, but I would say only go that route for very large number of files. If you're interested the script is part of the gentoolkit package, sources available here https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/gentoolkit.git

Comment: @Alex I found a partial way to figure out what you needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @xception! This is *exactly* what I was looking for.